# Supervisor is deleted when Ec2 Instance Terminates and Relaunch

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, supervisord

I installed Supervisor on an EC2 instance and it is working perfectly fine running my Laravel Queue. I noticed that every now and then, these instances auto-delete and create another instance to replace the old one and this also deletes the Supervisor I installed and thereby breaking my Queue flow.

Is there anyway I can prevent supervior and its config from deleting when these EC2 instances clone, delete and relaunch themselves?

Comment: Was the instance launched as part of an Auto Scaling group?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you are designing instance on AWS, people aim for them to be **stateless**.

This means that an instance can be terminated and replaced at any time without the impact on your application.

From your description it seems that your instances are not stateless, thus the issue.

There are  **few ways** of achieving that:

- Use [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) to bootstrap your instances to setup required software and configuration on an instance launch.
- construct [custom AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/best-practices-for-building-your-amis.html) so that it has all the software you require. Then set your launch template or launch configuration to use the AMI.
- use persistent storage for your data on instances. Common examples are keeping it in EFS, mutli-attached EBS volumes or a database, such as DynamoDb.

Apart from the above, you can **protect** your instances from being terminated:

- use [termination protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingDisableAPITermination)
- use [instance scale-in protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#instance-protection) when instances are in autoscaling group.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe suggests that the instance was launched as part of an **Auto Scaling group**.

An Auto Scaling group is designed to automatically launch new instances or terminate existing instances to **maintain a desired level of capacity**. The desired capacity level can increase and decrease throughout the day based upon load, as measured by a metric in Amazon CloudWatch, or the desired capacity remain constant and Auto Scaling simply replaces any instances that become 'unhealthy'.

When Auto Scaling **terminates an instance** (for example, to reduce capacity in quiet periods), the instance is deleted and the attached disk is also deleted.

When Auto Scaling **launches a new instance**, it uses a configured Amazon Machine Image (AMI), which contains the operating system and applications.

Thus, anything that you have manually installed on an instance will *not* be present on any newly-launched instances. If you want certain software or data to be available when a new instance is launched, follow the suggestions given by @Marcin:

- Automate installation via a **User Data script**
- Pre-install the software/data on an instance and then **create a new AMI**, and use that AMI in the Auto Scaling group configuration